# How to check the etTexthb object's current value

Tags: android

I am using two `textWatcher` objects, which are assigned to two `edittext`.  In my Android application, when one `editTextPer` is focusable, then I call the two methods

```
editTextHb.removeTextChangedListener(etTexthb);
editTextPer.addTextChangedListener(etTextper);
```

At this point, is `etTexthb` value `null` or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below check

```
if(etTexthb  == null) {
  // etTexthb  is null do needfull
}
else {
//etTexthb is not null
}
```